# Adding jQuery hover out to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Considering I have the following function notation:

```
$('a').bind('click hover', function(e)
```

How can I add actions for hover out, similarly to:

```
     $("a").hover(function() { //hover in stuff here
        }, function() {
        //hover out stuff here

        });
```

Comment: Please use mouseover ane mouseout event for same.

Comment: agree with @JayeshGoyani use mouseenter/mouseover for one and mouseout for the opposite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hover` doesnt really exist, it is just a shortcut of `mouseenter/mouseleave`. Just use that :

```
$('a').bind('click mouseenter mouseleave', function(e){});
```

Also, in newer version of jQuery, you should use `.on` instead of `.bind()`.

Also note that this :

```
 $("a").hover(function() { //hover in stuff here
    }, function() {
    //hover out stuff here

    });
```

is **not** the same as this :

```
$('a').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e){});
```

But the same as

```
$('a').bind({
    mouseenter : function(e){},
    mouseleave : function(e){}
});
```